# handlerbars template with auto height textarea

Tags: html, css, handlebars.net

I'm working on a C# project with handlebars for PDF generating, but I'm facing 1 issue, which is `textarea` wont show whole content due to it wont auto expand,

here my template code for the `textarea` and the sample input

```
description="line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n line 4\nline 5\n"

<textarea name="Description" class="form-control" disabled>
    {{description}}
</textarea>
```

I'm trying to use the css `resize: vertical` it works fine when browsing the template but after the pdf generated, it seems wont auto expand.

Is there anyway to fix this or other alternative route to do this ?

Comment: You can do it with js, or any js library...Check out this...
https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/frudD

Comment: @KunalKhatri question.. will this method still works after converted to PDF using handlebars?

Comment: You should first give auto height using this script, then convert to pdf, it'll work...

Comment: @KunalKhatri too bad it only will expand while is on focus, it won't expand if the text been assign into it

Comment: i hope you will be assigning the text to it using java script ot jquery, focusin that textarea before assigning text in it...Simple...